# Extension method selection using generic types and Expressions

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods, overloading

I have some extension methods that use an **Expression** parameter to pull in a property member and act on it, and I have an overload for the specific case where the member is an **IEnumerable<>**. However, it doesn't seem to match the expected method overload when called from inside a generic class (*for r4 below*). Outside of the class the correct method is selected.

What's going on here? Will this ever work or do I need to find a new approach?

(This is in C# 5)

```
public class Test
{
    public void MyTest()
    {
        // returns "Object"
        var r1 = new MyClass<object>().Ext(a => a.Content);

        // returns "Enumerable"
        var r2 = new MyClass<IEnumerable<object>>().Ext(a => a.Content);

        // returns "Object"
        var r3 = new MyClass<object>().TestExt();

        // returns "Object" (I was expecting "Enumerable")
        var r4 = new MyClass<IEnumerable<object>>().TestExt();

        // returns "Enumerable"
        var r5 = new MyClass<int>().TestExt2();
    }
}

public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T Content { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<object> OtherContent { get; set; }

    public string TestExt()
    {
        return this.Ext(a => a.Content);
    }

    public string TestExt2()
    {
        return this.Ext(a => a.OtherContent);
    }
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string Ext<T>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<object>>> memberExpression)
    {
        return "Enumerable";
    }

    public static string Ext<T>(this T obj, Expression<Func<T, object>> memberExpression)
    {
        return "Object";
    }
}
```

Comment: @KingKing See the comment next to the declaration of `r4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generics are not dynamic typing. Which overload to call is frozen at compile-time. When the program is later run, even if the variable happens to hold a more specific run-time type, that doesn't matter because the overload was fixed at compile-time.

Your method:

```
public string TestExt()
{
    return this.Ext(a => a.Content);
}
```

has to bind at compile-time to one specific overload of `Ext`. Since all we know about `T` (the type of `a.Content`) in the class `MyClass<T>` is that it is convertible to `object`, there is really only one overload to choose from, so this is easy for the compiler.

From then on, the `TestExt` method body is hard-coded to calling that specific overload of `Ext`.

---

EDIT: Here's a much simpler example:

```
static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<object> e = new List<object>();
    var r = Generic(e);
}

static string Generic<T>(T x)
{
    return Overloaded(x);
}

static string Overloaded(IEnumerable<object> x)
{
    return "Enumerable";
}
static string Overloaded(object x)
{
    return "Object";
}
```

and as you understand by now, `r` becomes `"Object"`.

(If you constrained `T` somehow, for example `where T : IEnumerable<object>`, things would be different).

Also this is the same for operators. For example the `==` operator is overloaded in the sense that it works in one way for general reference types, and in another for strings. So in the example below, operator `==` takes the role of `Overloaded` from before:

```
static void Main()
{
    string str1 = "abc";
    string str2 = "a";
    str2 += "bc";        // makes sure this is a new instance of "abc"

    bool b1 = str1 == str2;        // true
    bool b2 = Generic(str1, str2); // false
}

static bool Generic<T>(T x, T y) where T : class
{
    return x == y;
}
```

where `b2` becomes `false`.